# Recommendations for operational statistics gathering system

Tags: php, c++, linux, statistics, ipc

I have a web service running on Linux that consists of some PHP code that relies on a C++ program to do the heavy lifting. The PHP and C++ code runs once per transaction and then terminates. It is not (yet) persistent (i.e. a daemon), and yes, I know it would be more efficient if it were.

As transactions are completed, various bits of information are accumulated (which I collectively call "statistics" or "stats"). This information includes profiling information like execution times for various subtasks of the transaction, and logical information, like the nature and outcome of the transaction. These metrics are highly application-specific, so generalized monitoring and measurement tools are probably inappropriate here.

I want to start recording this information, but I don't want the act of recording it to interfere with performance. Specifically, I am assuming that I don't want to incur the cost of a database connection and teardown on every transaction, or block while waiting for write access to a file, for instance. I'd like to amortize this cost over many transactions, if possible. I don't care whether the statistics recording is done in the C++ or PHP code.

I am wondering if a good approach would be something that runs as a daemon on the server itself and receives statistics packets (perhaps JSON or protobufs or other packaging format). The delivery channel would be a socket or a pipe or some other kind of efficient IPC. These packets would be gathered into bundles and periodically stored to a database or otherwise moved off-server. Efficiency is realized by minimizing the processing per packet, and amortizing expensive operations across many packets.

My first question: Is the approach I have outlined above a viable and optimal one? Are there other designs I should be considering?

My second question: This feels like something that ought to already exist. Are there any general tools for Linux systems that receive, gather, and forward statistics packets?

Comment: Your self-suggestion of making this process run in a daemon certainly makes sense and you should definitely do it imho. Especially since you are aware of database connection setup/teardown issues. As to IPC, you have all the options, except one: the SysV IPC.

Comment: Interesting question. Would JSON or Protobufs really be any faster then just using MySQL? I was in a similar situation and resolved it by inserting the raw stats into a "dump" table, and then having a separate cron job examine and parse the data out of the dump table into my real stats tables so that the data collection wasn't hampered.

Comment: Yeah, @fge, daemonizing is probably coming, but that's a bigger task and lower priority than statistics gathering at this point in time. Visibility before performance, I suppose. I am hoping that there is some sort of off-the-shelf tool I can use for this. Otherwise, if I go the daemonization route, I may end up doing the stats gathering and forwarding in the daemon itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Julien. Can MySQL or SQLite be configured to run RAM-based (i.e. never touch disk)? That ought to be pretty quick.

Comment: yes, MySQL has memory tables. Not a bad idea either. Don't know too much about SQLite.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly off topic question first; why bother PHP at all, if you do all the work in C++? Quite curious to know your reasoning.

One of the popular statistics collection database is [RRD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.rrd.php), which is well supported in PHP. It is built for sampling statistical data.

Comment: It's legacy code (from my perspective), and the PHP front-end was there before I started working on the system. I think it was used basically because it is easier to implement an HTTP and JSON-based web service in PHP than C/C++. If I were starting fresh today, I wouldn't bother with the PHP at all. Thanks for the tip about RRD. I'll take a look.